# What is the difference between EBM and EBP?

Tags: terminology

I'm struggling to understand in simple terms the difference between EBM (evidence-based medicine) and EBP(evidence-based practice).

After a bit of research, this is what I have understood.
Is it correct? Would you add something?

---

**Evidence-Based Medicine (EBM)**
Approach to medical decision-making that emphasizes the use of the best available scientific evidence to guide clinical practice.

**Evidence-Based Practice (EBP)**
It's a broader term than EBM, encompassing the use of the best available evidence in various fields, including not only medicine but also nursing, social work, psychology, and other health professions.

In essence, EBM is a specific application of EBP in the field of medicine.

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference? Have you read somewhere that there is? This site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research, so please link to or cite the sources that lead you to ask this question.

Comment: Hi @CareyGregory, I added some more text with the outcome of my research on these two terms.

Comment: It seems like what you have is an adjective term "evidence-based" with a relatively clear definition. This term can then modify nouns, where the sum meaning of the adjective-noun pair depends both on the adjective and noun. That's how all adjectives work, isn't it? I guess I'm not seeing a place for a medical science question here about specific terminology, this is just use of language. You can put whatever you want in for the (noun) if you'd like to change scope: evidence-based cardiology, evidence-based management...